# Could you use All-Purpose Flour as a model rocket fuel?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment, fuel, explosives

I'm building a model rocket, and I'm trying to find a good fuel. I've done a lot of research and I know about r-candy and the aluminum-ammonium fuel, but I was wondering, before I made any of these, if I could use All-Purpose Flour instead. From what I've seen, it is highly combustible, and I think it would do a good job. However, it appears to burn slower than r-candy. Would it still burn fast enough to get a rocket launched? I also noticed that it doesn't pack easily, and I'm looking to make a solid rocket motor. Could I use water to pack it into the motor tube, then leave it to dry for a few days? Or could I pack it some other way?

Comment: Dust explosions, whether of flour, lycopodium spores or the stuff in hyperbaric explosives, can be very powerful. But bulk flour burns poorly: make a small pile and put a match to it. Not much happens. So you would need continual dust explosions to do the job and the developmental work would likely be substantial, at best.

Comment: With a nuclear explosion, maybe a steel manhole cover could be blasted into space: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Plumbbob. Or maybe not! ;-)

Comment: This is a great book, by John D. Clark, for anyone interested in rocket fuels: Ignition! An Informal History of Liquid Rocket Propellants, Rutgers University Press Classics, New Brunswick, NJ, ©1972 and 2017.

Comment: Make some tests. It should be the exciting part. That packing seems complicated as you will end with something more solid then pressed grains and removal of water will be hard to achieve.

Comment: The problem is that once it’s packed, you don’t have an oxidant. Solid rocket fuels contain fuel and oxidant, for example a nitrate, in order to get rapid combustion.

Comment: @Andrew If I were to mix a very finely ground chlorine with it, would that be a suitable oxidant? Would it be too powerful? Or, instead, what if I poured some liquid (10%) benzoyl-peroxide over the flour?

Comment: Chlorine is a gas, so you're going to have trouble grinding it. . . You need to find something kinetically stable enough that it won't oxidize the flour until it's ignited. I think benzoyl peroxide would start reacting right away. There's a lot of info out there on good solid fuel combinations that have already been worked out. I'd suggest sticking with those rather than trying to reinvent them.

Comment: I strongly caution against grinding fuels and oxidizers together! Even just mixing finely ground fuels and oxidizers can be very dangerous. Long ago, I was grinding sulfur powder with an oxidizer that I will not name. I was taking what I thought were reasonable safety precautions and the grinding was going well. **Until the ignition!** I got molten sulfur on my thumb, raced out to the creek in back and submerged my hand. Turns out the sulfur and that “chlorine” oxidizer spontaneously ignite after a few hours, so I am very glad I did not make up a batch and store it. Safety first!

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. I also think all comments by @EdV are already close to an answer. (I'm encouraging you to write one.)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I will think about it, but I am not an explosives expert, unlike, say, matt_black (my inference based on his generally excellent answers). I have had my share of explosions when I was *much* younger (basement lab; lots of curiosity; minimal parental supervision), but aside from strongly cautioning against grinding fuels and oxidizers together, I was just providing a little food for thought.

Comment: @EdV I respect your decision. I (and I guess others, too) value your contributions in whatever form they come. I'm hopeful the OP gained some insight. I also do admit that I've used your commentary as a point (maybe even excuse) to justify not closing this question.